# Conditional not triggering after value change

Tags: swiftui

ok I'm working on a first swiftui app as a way of learning and have used conditionals to colour some buttons. The problem is when the related state changes (Bool) the conditional isn't being updated. I thought this was to do with a UI redraw not being triggered due to state however I can't seem to figure out a solution to that.

Background info: task is an instance of the Task class (passed in from another view) which is an array on the ModelData Environment object. when the button is clicked the related value (isHotList) is indeed changed but the image colour isn't changed.

```
@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
var task: Task

                    Button(action: {
                    task.isHotList.toggle()
                }){
                    Image(systemName: "flame.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(task.isHotList ? Color.orange : Color.gray)
                }
```

Comment: try this: "@State var task: Task" or "@Binding var task: Task"

Comment: I tried setting it as an State earlier which had no perceptible effect and using Binding throws an error on the preview.

Comment: ha, I see your Task is a class not a struct. If it was a struct it probably would work with "@State..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `Test` an observable object, like

```
class Task: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isHotList = false
  // ... other content here
}
```

and make `test` property in view wrapped into `ObservedObject`, like

```
@EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
@ObservedObject var task: Task                 // << here !!
```

Alternatively make the `Task` as struct and then you can use either `@State` or `@Binding` for `task` property (depending on your design).